# How to create Box Plot for a series of data without x values

Tags: c#

I am having difficulty creating a box plot for a set of row objects contained in a list. The data itself is populating fine enough but the chart creates a different x value for each object in the list, which is not intended. Perhaps I am using the wrong binding method on the list? Here is the snippet of code in which the binding occurs:

```
foreach (DataRow row in myDataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
{
   colValues.Add(row["Freight Cost/ Pc - $"]);
}

chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.DataBindY(colValues);
```

edit:

It is a list. It contains each row value of column "Freight Cost/ Pc -$". I believe I only have one series. It is currently creating an x value for each y value in the list. I want only one independent value for every y value. In other words, I am dealing with a univariate sample. I don't even get why this is an issue. I was under the impression that a box plot was strictly used to display descriptive statistics related to univariate data.

Comment: This is not enough info. What is `colValues` ? Do you have one Series or more? How does it and how should it look?

Comment: Have you resolved your problems?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `DataPoint` of `ChartType` [BoxPlot](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456709%28VS.100%29.aspx) is a graphical depiction of statistical data.

You have two basic ways to use a `BoxPlot` chart:

- You can add multiple `DataPoints` e.g. by using the `AddXY` call. For this you will have to provide (at least) **six Y-Values** containing the statistical values to show.
- Or you can 'bind' a `DataPoint` **to another Series in the Chart**. If you have multiple `Series` you can show their stats in one `BoxPlot DataPoint` each.

The main difference is that in the first case you need to already have the stats while the second way will let the chart do the calculations on the series of `DataPoints`. The way to make that work is **not by normal data binding** but by using the `BoxPlotSeries` **custom property**:

```
Series BS = chart1.Series.Add("BoxPlotSeries");
BS.ChartType = SeriesChartType.BoxPlot;
BS.Points.Add(new DataPoint(55, 0));
BS.Points[0]["BoxPlotSeries"] = "S1";
```

After creating a random series `S1` with 50 `DataPoints`, I create a `BoxPlot` series, add one point at `x=55` and relate the point's [Custom property `BoxPlotSeries`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456764.aspx)

Here is a result:

[image]

By **regular binding** the `Points` to your `List` you have effectively chosen method one and see **many** `BoxPlot` points. Instead style the `Series` to your liking as `chartType Point, Line, Column` or what you want; then add a **second** `Series` with **one** `DataPoint`, **relating** it to the data series, like in my code example..

I have chosen my `X-Value` so that the `BoxPlot` point sits to the right of the data. If your data do not have meaningful i.e. numeric X-Values they are displayed in order and you can place the `BoxPlot` point at `S1.Points.Count` or `Count + 1 or +2`..

**Note** that if you have a lot of `DataPoints` the BoxPlotPoint will look so thin you can hardly see it at all.

In that case it would be nice if you could simply make it wider.

There is a set of Custom Properties, namely

[PointWidth](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456723%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)  and [PixelPointWidth](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456636%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), [MinPixelPointWidth](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456637%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [MaxPixelPointWidth](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456640%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

```
BS["MinPixelPointWidth"] = "15";
BS["MaxPixelPointWidth"] = "25";
```

But you may prefer to keep the BoxPlot points separate by adding a second `ChartArea` where you place the BoxPlot series:

[image]

Here are the positioning and styling calls used for the above screenshot:

```
ChartArea A1 = chart1.ChartAreas[0];
Series S1 = chart1.Series[0];
A1.AxisX.Interval = 50;

ChartArea A2 = chart1.ChartAreas.Add("A2");
A2.AlignWithChartArea = "A1";
A2.AlignmentOrientation = AreaAlignmentOrientations.Horizontal;
A2.AlignmentStyle = AreaAlignmentStyles.PlotPosition;
A1.Position.Width *= 0.85f;
A2.Position.Y = A1.Position.Y;
A2.Position.X = A1.Position.Right;
A2.Position.Width = A1.Position.Width * 0.15f;

A2.AxisX.LabelStyle.ForeColor = Color.Transparent;
A2.AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
A2.AxisX.MajorTickMark.Enabled = false;
A2.AxisX.Minimum = 0;
A2.AxisX.Maximum = 2;
A2.AxisY.Interval = 10;
A2.AxisY.Maximum = A1.AxisY.Maximum;
A2.AxisY.Minimum = A1.AxisY.Minimum;

Series BS = chart1.Series.Add("BoxPlotSeries");
BS.ChartArea = "A2";
BS.ChartType = SeriesChartType.BoxPlot;
BS.Points.Add(new DataPoint(1, 0));
DataPoint DPT = BS.Points[BS.Points.Count - 1];
DPT["BoxPlotSeries"] = "S1";
```

By adding a second, slightly more random data series and a second boxplot point you can show the different distributions:

[image]

Note that you need to set the data Series.Colors explictly to allow referencing them for the BoxPlot points..:

```
 S1.Color = Color.SteelBlue;
 S2.Color = Color.DarkKhaki;
 ...
 DPT1.Color = chart1.Series["S1"].Color;
 DPT2.Color = chart1.Series["S2"].Color;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You provided a very detailed answer.

Comment: If you have questions do ask! - If you are happy with the answer, please consider [accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it..!